# необходим программа,которая будет сортировать массив 2мя потоками одновременно(пузырьком и выбором)

Tags: c#

В программе должны использоваться следующие механизмы:
•    для одновременного запуска процессов необходимо использовать семафор, т.е. поток, который в коде запускается первым, должен ожидать запуск второго потока.
•   правильность сортировки массива должна быть обеспечена с помощью критических секций.
•   в программе должна быть предусмотрена возможность отключения критических секций, при этом необходимо показать , что массив будет отсортирован неверно (для увеличения вероятности возникновения ошибки рекомендуется использовать оператор sleep()).
•   Вывод результата сортировки массива. Массив должен выводиться главным потоком. Он должен ожидать окончание сортировки массива двумя вспомогательными потоками. Ожидание реализовать с помощью семофоров.

Я смог написать коды генерации и сортировки по отдельности, но как это объединить и сделать через потоки не знаю, помогите кто может.
В windows form первый раз работаю, поэтому код не очень)

```
//генерация массива
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Random rnd = new Random();
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
         int[] arr = new int[num];
         for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
         {
             arr[i] = rnd.Next(-100, 100);
             textBox2.Text +=arr[i].ToString()+" ";
         }
     }
//функция сортировки
public void Sort_puzir(int[] arr)
     {
         int num = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
         int temp;
         for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < num - i - 1; j++)
             {
                 if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
                 {
                     temp = arr[j];
                     arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                     arr[j + 1] = temp;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
//функция сортировки
     public void Sort_chose(int [] arr)
     {
         int num = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
         int min, temp;

         for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; i++)
         {
             min = i;

             for (int j = i + 1; j < num; j++)
             {
                 if (arr[j] < arr[min])
                     min = j;
             }
             temp = arr[i];
             arr[i] = arr[min];
            arr[min] = temp;
         }

     }
//многопоточность
     private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         int num = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); 
         string s = textBox2.Text;
         string[] arrstring = new string[1];
         if (s != "")
         {
             arrstring = s.Split(' ');
         }
         int[] mas = new int[arrstring.Length - 1];
         for (int i = 0; i < arrstring.Length - 1; i++)
         {
             mas[i] = Convert.ToInt32(arrstring[i]);
         }

         Thread myThread1 = new Thread(() => Sort_puzir(mas));
         myThread1.Start();
         myThread1.Join();
         Thread myThread2 = new Thread(() => Sort_chose(mas));
         myThread2.Start();
         myThread2.Join();
         for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
             textBox5.Text += mas[i].ToString() + "  ";
     }

     private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Вы не знаете как создать поток? Или как его запустить? Или как создать семафор? В документации куча примеров этого.

Comment: я знаю как создать и запустить потоки, про семафор тоже читал, но как реализовать одновременную сортировку массива двумя разными способами я не совсем понимаю. Как должны взаимодействовать потоки между собой?

Comment: семафор и предназначен для синхронизации потоков. Вы начните писать код, вот вы создали поток, с одной сортировкой, потом создали поток с другой сортировкой, запустили их одновременно, увидели результат - это уже половина вашего задания. После создали семафор, примеров как им остановить поток полно - остановили один поток, второй как закончил работу, дал сигнал семафору, и первый поток отработал после того, как второй закончился - вот и все ваше задание.

Comment: как сделать массив общедоступным?
где его объявлять, чтобы везде он был доступен.
просто у меня получается, что потоки сортируют параллельно два одинаковых массива(т.е. разные массивы)

Comment: у меня кое-что получилось я код изменил, можете сказать верно ли я это сделал?
пока без семафора.
сортирует верно (даже без ошибок, меня это и настараживает)

Comment: Ну оно так и должно быть, вы же сейчас запускаете поток и ждете его конца, потом только запускаете второй поток. Попробуйте запустить потоки параллельно.

Comment: Как их запустить параллельно?
если я убираю строки:
myThread1.Join();
myThread2.Join();
то программа не сортирует массив

Comment: И впринципе программа работает не правильно так как я передаю исходный массив в функцию  и он там отдельно от другого потока сортируется и поэтому ошибки сортировки не будет,даже если я запущу их паралельно